# how to find control of dropdownlist inside a datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a DataList and inside it I have a DropDownList:

```
  <asp:DataList ID="dlconfigureItem" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList CssClass="config-select" ID="ddlitem    runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
  </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:DataList>
```

How can I get selectedindexchanged event of DropDownList on the server side? I tried this:

```
   public void ddlitem_selectedindexchanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

but it is not working.

Comment: Not sure if this is a type o, but you are also missing the closing " on your id of your dropdownlist.

Answer (score 1):

From the `SelectedIndexChanged` event the easiest is to cast the `sender` to the `DropDownList`

```
var ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
```

The *sender* is always the control that is the source of the event.

For the sake of completeness, from `ItemDataBound` of the `DataList`:

```
protected void dlconfigureItem_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e) 
{
    DropDownList ddlitem = e.Item.FindControl("ddlitem") as DropDownList;
    if (ddlitem != null)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Have you forgotten to register the event?

```
<asp:DropDownList CssClass="config-select" 
    ID="ddlitem" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlitem_selectedindexchanged"    
    runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Note that you should not bind your DataList to it's DataSource on postbacks, otherwise events are not triggered. So check for the `IsPostBack` property of the page.

For example in `page_load`:

```
if(!IsPostBack)BindDataList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the server side method:

```
public void ddlitem_selectedindexchanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

but you have not told client side that there is an event for you, so in html code tell it like:

```
 onselectedindexchanged="ddlitem_selectedindexchanged"
```

and also set AutoPostBack property to true.

Comment: and yeh as Tim said: "Note that you should not bind your DataList to it's DataSource on postbacks, otherwise events are not triggered."  Do check it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Register the event and set `AutoPostBack="true"`

```
<asp:DropDownList CssClass="config-select" 
    ID="ddlitem" 
    AutoPostBack="true"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlitem_selectedindexchanged"    
    runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

event (on selected index change you can get the selected value)

```
    protected void ddlCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ddlList = (DropDownList)sender;
        string selectedValue = ((DropDownList)ddlList.NamingContainer.FindControl("ddlitem")).SelectedValue;   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can't get the selected item on the server or you can't find the way to handle the event. In case your problem is with the event handling, try this

```
  <asp:DataList ID="dlconfigureItem" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList CssClass="config-select" ID="ddlitem" 
       OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlitem_selectedindexchanged" 
       AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
  </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:DataList>
```